# kafka_2.11-0.9.0.1 Java client cannot retrieve message

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am new to kafka, I installed the latest version of kafka and successfully published some messages to a topic "test" with 0.9.0.1 Java producer API. These messages are available from command line tool and other third party tool.
However, whatever I tried, I cannot read these messages with new high level consumer API. Basically I copied the code from the sample code.

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("bootstrap.servers", kafkaServer);
props.put("group.id", "testgroup");
props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
props.put("session.timeout.ms", "30000");
props.put("key.deserializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
props.put("value.deserializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");

KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
consumer.subscribe(topics);
ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);
```

Here is always return an empty set. If I call 
    Set partitions = consumer.assignment(); 
The result is also empty.
Did I miss something?

Another problem is, is "group.id" a required prop for consumer? If I remove "group.id" property, an exception of "invalid group id" is thrown when poll. What if we don't need a consumer group in some cases?

Comment: I tried to do some debug, it seems that the client actually read some messages from the broker. However, it also caught some exceptions like org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.SendFailedException, org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: Commit cannot be completed due to group rebalance and org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnknownMemberIdException: The coordinator is not aware of this member. I don't know where these exceptions came from.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I am having a similar [same] problem.